# How to specify session-descriptor in weblogic.xml before application deployment using WLST in jython

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

I am configuring weblogic.xml to include below tags.

```
<session-descriptor>
  <timeout-secs>3600</timeout-secs>
  <invalidation-interval-secs>60</invalidation-interval-secs>
  <cookie-name>ADMINCONSOLESESSION</cookie-name>
  <cookie-path>/console/</cookie-path>
  <cookie-max-age-secs>-1</cookie-max-age-secs>
  <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
  <cookie-http-only>true</cookie-http-only> 
  <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

I want to configure all this using WLST.

I think it can be done using deployment plan option but i am not sure if the above tags will be available by default or i have to create a new variable?

below links i am referring to.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13715/updateplan.htm#WLSTG226

Answer (score 0):

All tags from weblogic.xml are updatable with a deployment plan. You need to create a variable definition for each tag you need to add/update in the plan.  The documentation explains how to update an existing deployment plan. Then, your application must be deployed with a plan before you can use WLST commaands to update the plan.